# compare variable with $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Tags: php

I have got variable `$page`. This Variable holds the value of the page on which I am.
Need to compare this expression:

`if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === '/index.php?page='.$page)`

but its not working

Comment: `var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);` What's the output?

Comment: I'd start with var_dump($_SERVER). Chanses are you're under PHP7 which doesn't auto-populate $_SERVER

Comment: @user247245 Citation?

Comment: It may be returning the full path, including the domain name. Depending on the web server configuration.

Comment: @JonStirling, I was thinking of auto_globals_jit and I'm wrong. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @user247245 Np. You had me worried for a minute there ;)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it would be much more simple to do:

```
if ($_GET['page'] == $page)
```

This would also continue to work if you have more than just page in your query string.